# graph.facebook.com and FacebookConnect on iPhone: How can I remove a "like"

Tags: iphone, facebook, http-delete

I'm developing an iPhone application using the Facebook Connect API. I arrived to set the "Like" on a post using the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/likes", discussion.postId]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:[self.facebook accessToken] forKey:@"access_token"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

It generates the following call:

HTTP POST https://graph.facebook.com/147512198609691_148877991806445/likes

But I'm not able to do the inverse operation "Unlike" (removing the like
from the post).

I tried the following:

HTTP POST https://graph.facebook.com/147512198609691_148877991806445/likes?access_token=....&method=delete

and also:

HTTP DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/147512198609691_148877991806445/likes?access_token=....

But those are not working, probably I'm using a wrong command.

Answer (score 0):

```
[request setPostValue:@"DELETE" forKey:@"method"];
```